# .main::after is not covering the entire height of .main in mobile view

Tags: css

I set a ::after to my .main div. In laptop and desktop, the .main::after is covering the whole .main div but not when in mobile view. I tried to set both .main and main::after heights to 100% but still not achieving the desired design.

this is the laptop view:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AuOO.jpg)

this is the mobile view:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnEaC.png)

I want  the gradient color to be still visible on the lower part in mobile view.

this is my desired result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iYmw.png)

in this image, i set the height property of .main::after to 143% but I know that it won't be enough. it wont fit in other devices screen sizes.

for more reference you may check my github repository

repository name: resume-sample-exercise
repository url: https://github.com/MikhelRhyz/resume-sample-exercise
live url: https://mikhelrhyz.github.io/resume-sample-exercise/

```css
    * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main {
  background: url("images/business-man-2452808_1280.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

.main::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    118deg,
    rgb(4, 25, 38),
    rgba(102, 128, 154, 0.5)
  );
}

.container-fluid {
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  background-color: rgb(4, 25, 38);
  max-width: 17rem;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 1rem;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.headset {
  color: rgb(3, 163, 212);
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.text-bold {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.text-normal {
  font-weight: normal;
}

hr {
  margin: 2px 0;
}

.name {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.lower-nav-links a {
  color: rgb(78, 99, 121);
  padding: 1.5rem 0;
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(9, 28, 42);
}

.lower-nav-links li:last-child a {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.slogan-container {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  margin: 7rem 0;
  width: 75%;
}

.slogan {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.play-audio {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}

.play-audio img {
  width: 10%;
}

.play-audio .soundwave {
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  max-height: 17rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 667px) {
  nav {
    overflow: scroll;
  }

  .slogan-container {
    margin: 1.5rem 0;
    width: 60%;
  }

  .slogan {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 414px) {
  .main {
    background-position: center left;
    height: 100%;
  }

  nav {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
    float: none;
  }

  .profile li {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .slogan-container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
  }

  .slogan {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .play-audio {
    padding: 0 2rem;
  }
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/eeda5486a2.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />

    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="clearfix container-fluid main">
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav flex-column">
          <div class="profile p-1 pb-4">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link active text-white text-bold">
                <span class="name"
                  >Rhyz Del<span
                    ><i class="fa-solid fa-headset headset"></i
                  ></span>
                  Cruz</span
                >
                <hr />
                <span class="title text-normal">Front-end Developer</span>
              </a>
            </li>
          </div>
          <div class="text-center lower-nav-links">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i>
                <br />
                About
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-lightbulb"></i>
                <br />
                Experience
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-headphones"></i>
                <br />
                Demo
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-quote-right"></i>
                <br />
                Reviews
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                <i class="fa-brands fa-telegram"></i>
                <br />
                Contact
              </a>
            </li>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="slogan-container">
        <div class="slogan">
          Design.
          <br />
          Develop.
          <br />
          Delight.
        </div>
        <div class="play-audio">
          <img src="images/arrow-30330_640.png" alt="play button" />
          <img
            src="images/61668-removebg-preview.png"
            class="soundwave"
            alt="soundwave"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end of main div  -->
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried using chatgpt to solve but to no avail. I also tried to google but I can't find the answer.

Comment: can you elaborate moe about your difficulty, what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.
The same is true for all other HTML tags.

Comment: how do we reproduce your problem? your code snippet does not reflect the screenshot provided

Comment: Why are you switching from `height: 100vh` to `height: 100%` in your `max-width: 414px` media query?

Answer (score -1):

Can you please check the below solution? Hope it will work for you.

you have add just add `z-index` in `.main::after` to cover full height of main element.

```
.main::after {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

you have to just manage z-index of all the elements.

Comment: still not covering the entire height in mobile view. what it did is bring the background gradient in front but still just covering the upper part